# Brace Expansion in Quotes

Tags: bash

I understand that brace expansion in Bash will expand to multiple arguments. Can I have it expand to a single argument?

Is there a pure solution to this in Bash, without resorting to the nested echo?

**Actual Behaviour**

`command arg{1,2,3}`

```
$1 = arg1
$2 = arg2
$3 = arg3
```

**Desired Behaviour**

```
$1 = arg1 arg2 arg3
$2 = 
$3 =
```

**Non-Solution**

`command "arg{1,2,3}"`

```
$1 = arg{1,2,3}
$2 = 
$3 =
```

**Potential Solution** (a little hack-y?)

`command "$(echo arg{1,2,3})"`

```
$1 = arg1 arg2 arg3
$2 = 
$3 =
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding `arg{1,2,3}` to `arg1 arg2 arg3` is called Brace Expansion, splitting that into three words is called Word Splitting and inserting a command’s output Command Substitution. `man bash` says:

> The  order  of  expansions  is:  **brace  expansion**; tilde expansion,
>   parameter and variable
>          expansion, arithmetic  expansion,  and  **command  substitution**  (done  in  a  left-to-right
>          fashion); **word splitting**; and pathname expansion.

In a command line like

```bsh
printf %s\\n {1..3}
```

Brace Expansion happens first and makes it

```bsh
printf %s\\n 1 2 3
```

where `1`, `2` and `3` are separate words thanks to Word Splitting. There’s nothing you can do to change this order – as you experienced, quoting it does not only prevent Word Splitting, but Brace Expansion as well. You can however use Command Substitution to get a Brace Expansion even inside double quotes:

> If  the [command] substitution  appears within double quotes, **word splitting**
>   and pathname expansion are **not performed** on the results.

In

```bsh
printf %s\\n "$(echo {1..3})"
```

the inner of the quotes is expanded first

```bsh
printf %s\\n "$(echo 1 2 3)"
printf %s\\n "1 2 3"
```

and as the result is quoted it is not subject to Word Splitting:

```bsh
$ printf %s\\n {1..3} "{1..3}" "$(echo {1..3})" # prints one argument per line
1
2
3
{1..3}
1 2 3
```

This is indeed not only the simplest way to do this, but also a pure `bash` solution, as `echo` is a `bash` builtin.